# How to upload multiple images into PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, html

**Hello everyone,**
I have a table consist of 10 columns which in 4 of them i want to insert the image paths. 

can any one guide me how to insert the image paths into database along with other 6 more columns data in a single query and upload the images into server(inside a folder).

**here my html code:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Product full name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" name="name2" type="text">
</div>
```

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Product category</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault2" name="name1" type="text">
</div>
```

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Product qty</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault3" name="name3" type="text">
</div>
```

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Picture 1.</label>
    <input type="file" id="file3" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Picture 2.</label>
    <input type="file" id="file3" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Picture 3.</label>
    <input type="file" id="file3" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="align-content:center" for="inputdefault">Picture 4.</label>
    <input type="file" id="file3" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</div>
```

**Here php code :** 
*Note:* I did not get image file names in any variable to added into query, everything is working fine here just need to work with images upload and store the path in to database

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$pname= stripslashes($_REQUEST['name1']);
$pcat= stripslashes($_REQUEST['name2']);
$pprice= stripslashes($_REQUEST['name3']);
$pqty= stripslashes($_REQUEST['qty']);
$pdesc=stripslashes($_REQUEST['description']);
//$spassword=stripslashes($_REQUEST['img']);



$sqlinsert ="INSERT INTO `noorizone`.`products` VALUES ('$pname', '$pcat', '$pprice')";

    if($con-> query($sqlinsert)=== true)
{
    echo "<center><b style='color:green;'> added  successfully... </b>";
    echo"</center>";
}
else{
    echo "<b style='color:red;'> cant register". $con->error."</b>";
}
}
?>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is example for me, you can learn my codes :

```
$fileImageStatus = "";                      // Create your variable for files
if(isset($_FILES['files_status']['name'])){ // Checking value for all input
  $fileImageName = array();                 // Make an array
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files_status']['name']); $i++){ // Looping
      $imageName = $_FILES['files_status']['name'][$i];         // Give a variable with index from array looped
      $uploadPath = '././sistem/users/members/'.$idPenerima.'/unggahan/';
      move_uploaded_file($imageTmp, $uploadPath.$imageName);    // Path upload
      $fileImageName[] = $imageName;                           // Setting a values from array
  }
      $fileImageStatus = implode(",", $fileImageName);         // Make that values an string
   }
  // in here you can insert to database with value from $fileImageStatus
```

Comment: You are not making any sense. You just copied and pasted this code. OP is clearly a novice in php. Add explanations or people would down vote

Comment: Because one from us have an own busy.  Ok, i will give a explanation

Comment: @Akintunde can you please give the answer with explanation

Comment: @user8455694 thnks i got it, let me apply it once.

Comment: @user8455694 can you please update the code as my own written code, i tried but did not understand it fully, thnks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the name of the file to say file1 instead of file[], you will be fine.

See an example from [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!--
<?php


$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}




?>
-->
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i saw that as well but am asking for multiple file uploading

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Good tutorial on how to upload multiple images into PHP and Mysql

http://www.wdb24.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-php-and-store-in-mysql/